# file_exists(): Unable to find the wrapper "sftp" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, expressionengine

This is the error I get on a fresh Ubuntu Server 14.04 install.

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Warning

Message: file_exists(): Unable to find the wrapper "sftp" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Filename: libraries/Template.php

Line Number: 2610
```

Comment: Error message seems to explain the error. I'm sure solutions can be found with an online search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to install and enable the ssh2 extension without results! I was sure that this would solve the issue, until I found out that I was trying to access the local file via sftp://srv/.. rather than just /srv/.. (ouch!)

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a [ssh2 extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2) enabled and use `ssh2.sftp://` schema instead of `sftp://`.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you really need to process sftp remote file then:

1. Install [ssh2](http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2) extension for PHP. How to install and enable: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php
   https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-install-the-php-ssh2-extension/
2. Test that it is successfull:

   ```
   php -r "phpinfo();"|grep "ssh2"

   php -r "ssh2_connect('ftp.someHost.com');"
   ```
3. use in your application

Also, the issue can be in the host name:
it is NOT supposed to have protocol in it like:

```
sftp://subdomain.domain.com
```

I changed to:

```
subdomain.domain.com
```

And it started to work.